# How to automate letters icon creation with free tools

Tags: icon, automation

I must say im not designer im programmer im building simple game for my kids 
in this game i need to create many sets of english letters icons like this   ones im attaching.
now im doing it using Inkscape . and its very hard work to create 26 letters 
each time .
is there any tool or way to design the first letter icon and then just create all the rest of the letters by this design ?
this what i have for example :
[image] 
[image]
[image]
and so on ..

Comment: Not that I know of in inkscape. However, what are you building the game in? It might be easier to do this in code. For example, those look fairly easy to replicate with SVG or even CSS.

Comment: im using cocos2d-x c++ , it is not supporting css or SVG